# Display Ads in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, ads

I am trying to display Ads in Android's Webview. The JS snippet that is given below needs to be embedded in the webview:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Ad URL"></script>
```

The URL contains the following code:

```
    document.write('<a target="_blank" 
     href="valid URL">
     <img src="valid Image" border=0></a>');
```

Here's how am doing it in my activity:

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.adWebView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadURL("Valid URL");
```

The above code does not display the Ad image but it displays the javascript code in the webview. Please advise me how to display the image in the webview and not the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be working on this anymore, but for anyone else finding this thread - I just created a tutorial on how to show an html/javascript ad in a webview.  The simplest thing to do would be to grab my project and swap your javascript in:

http://www.projectjourneyman.com/leadbolt-show-ads-in-android-webview

I think the critical difference is loading the data differently - try this, where "html" is a string with the full HTML snippet:

```
wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```